# Converter string em inteiro

Tags: c#, .net, string, conversão-de-tipo, int

Não estou conseguindo converter o texto do meu `TextBox` em inteiro.

```
namespace Pag98_Exe1
{
    public partial class frmveiculos : Form
    {
        public frmveiculos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Veiculos veiculos = new Veiculos(); //Declarando a classe veiculos

        private void btnenviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(mskTxtplaca.Text != "" && cbxmarca.Text != "" && txtanofabricacao.Text != "")
            {
                veiculos.Placa = mskTxtplaca.Text; //Atribuindo o valor de Placa ao texto do TextBox
                veiculos.Marca = cbxmarca.Text;
                veiculos.AnoFabricacao(int.Parse(txtanofabricacao.Text)); //Passando o valor do TextBox para inteiro e atribuindo ao TextBox
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: @bigown Gravidade Código Descrição Projeto Arquivo Linha Estado de supressão
Erro CS0029 Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "string" em "int" Pag98_Exe1 C:\Users\home\Desktop\Trabalhos COTEMIG\Pag98_Exe1\Pag98_Exe1\frmveiculos.cs 28 Ativo

Comment: @bigown a linha do erro é a 3ª dentro da condição if

Comment: Já tentou Convert.toInt32() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o texto vem de um controle que o usuário pode digitar não há garantias que o texto pode ser convertido para inteiro, então tem que tentar fazer, se der certo faz o que deseja, caso contrário precisa tratar isso de alguma forma, emitir um erro, colocar um valor padrão, alguma coisa assim. Isso se faz com o método [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__). Outras soluções são falhas, não use a não ser que tenha certeza que o valor poderá ser convertido, o que não parece ser o caso. Tenho minhas dúvidas se o resto da lógica é adequada, mas não posso falar sem conhecer os requisitos.

```
private void btnenviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(mskTxtplaca.Text != "" && cbxmarca.Text != "" && txtanofabricacao.Text != "") {
        veiculos.Placa = mskTxtplaca.Text;
        veiculos.Marca = cbxmarca.Text;
        int anoFabricacao;
        if (int.TryParse(txtanofabricacao.Text, out anoFabricacao) {
            veiculos.AnoFabricacao = anoFabricacao;
        } else {
            //aqui coloque o que deve fazer se a conversão falhar
        }
    }
}
```

Em C# 7 pode fazer um pouco mais simples:

```
private void btnenviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(mskTxtplaca.Text != "" && cbxmarca.Text != "" && txtanofabricacao.Text != "") {
        veiculos.Placa = mskTxtplaca.Text;
        veiculos.Marca = cbxmarca.Text;
        if (int.TryParse(txtanofabricacao.Text, out var anoFabricacao) {
            veiculos.AnoFabricacao = anoFabricacao;
        } else {
            //aqui coloque o que deve fazer se a conversão falhar
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/TryParse.cs).

Comment: Muito boa a explicação, aproveitando, você sabe me dizer como deixar certos espaços de um text box mascarado para receber apenas um tipo de caractere ? Ex: Placa de veiculo (AAA-0000) a parte em que está as letras só recebe letras e a que estão os numeros apenas numeros

Comment: @CaioVieira dê uma olha no [tour], a gente é diferente de um fórum, então cada dúvida precisa estar em uma pergunta diferente para que ela possa ser avaliada independentemente por todo mundo e que possa ajudar outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema. Nem daria para responder apropriadamente em um comentário curto e com baixa capacidade de formatação. Mas parece estar no caminho certo em usar o {`MaskedTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Obrigado pela força ai

Answer (score 2):

Seu posto tá um pouco confuso, pelo o que eu entendi do código tenta essa solução:

```
veiculos.AnoFabricacao = int.Parse(txtanofabricacao.Text);
```

Comment: Deu certo meu amigo, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: aceita a resposta ai

Comment: Só daqui a 5 min.