# Como desserializar um json para int?

Tags: c#, json

Tenho um json de teste para ver se minha implementação funcionou no meu código:

```
string json = @"{'ItemHome':[{'Texto':'111','Icone':'aaaa','Color':'aaaa'}, {'Texto':'111','Icone':'aaaa','Color':'aaaa'}, {'Texto':'111','Icone':'aaaa','Color':'aaaa'}, {'Number':'531141884','ContactName':'ftftft'}]}";
```

e deserializo ele da seguinte forma:

```
Model Dados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
```

e minha model:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<ModelHome> ItemHome { get; set; }
}

public class ModelHome
{
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public int Icone { get; set; }
    public int Color { get; set; }
}
```

Porém apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Unhandled Exception:
>        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to integer: aaaa. Path 'ItemHome[0].Icone', line 1, position 42.

Como converter os valores para `int`?

Comment: Como disse "Tenho um json de teste para ver se minha implementação funcionou no meu código:" só preciso saber como faz para converter um valor para int

Comment: Esse rollback nao foi nada inteligente. Já conhece o `int.Parse` e o `int.TryParse`?

Comment: Por que você reverteu a minha edição?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No seu JSON de testes, as propriedades `Icone` e `Color` estão recebendo o valor de **aaaa**. Logicamente, **aaaa** não é um valor inteiro.

Caso tenha certeza que o valor será um texto, altere o tipo das propriedades para `String`, que deverá resolver o seu problema.

```
public class ModelHome
{
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public string Icone { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Caso você passe valores numéricos ao invés de **aaaa**, não é necessário alterar o tipo das propriedades.

Ironicamente, o valor da propriedade `Texto` que possui o tipo `String`, está recebendo o valor **1111**, que pode ser numérico.

#### Atualização

Caso queira, você também pode criar um [CustomJsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) para tentar realizar a conversão do tipo `String` para `Int` no momento da deserialização do JSON.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

Converter:

```
public class StringToIntConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(int?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer)
            return reader.Value;

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)reader.Value))
                return null;
            int num;
            //Tenta converter o valor
            if (int.TryParse((string)reader.Value, out num))
            {
                return num;
            }
            //Retorna 0
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }
        throw new JsonReaderException(string.Format("Unexcepted token {0}", reader.TokenType));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

E em seu Model, basta colocar a anotação:

```
public class ModelHome
{
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringToIntConverter))]
    public int Icone { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringToIntConverter))]
    public int Color { get; set; }
}
```

Desta forma, ele sempre irá tentar converter de `String` para `int`. Caso não consiga, irá retornar o valor de 0;

Para maiores detalhes de como converter `String` para `int`, [veja esta resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160339/20615)

Para maiores detalhes sobre o `CustomJsonConverter`, veja [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863522/4843158) ou a [própria documentação do Newtonsoft.](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Answer (score 4):

O erro é muito claro. As propriedades `Icone` e `Color` estão declaradas como `int` e no JSON elas têm **uma string como valor**.

Eu não sei qual a real intenção disto, mas se o JSON estiver errado, arrume os valores neles, se for a declaração na sua model que estiver errada, mude as propriedades de `int` para `string`.

Outro problema é que o último item da lista não tem as propriedades corretas, isso está certo?

```
public class ModelHome
{
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public string Icone { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo do JSON

```
string json = @"{'ItemHome': [{'Texto':'111','Icone':'1','Color':'2'}, 
                              {'Texto':'111','Icone':'2','Color':'1'}, 
                              {'Texto':'111','Icone':'1','Color':'3'}, 
                              {'Number':'531141884','ContactName':'ftftft'}]}";
```

Comment: Como disse "Tenho um json de teste para ver se minha implementação funcionou no meu código:" só preciso saber como faz para converter um valor para int